# Generic overridden method with subclass as return type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Let's say that i have a base class Animal.

```
public abstract class Animal;
```

This animal class has the abstract method:

```
public abstract T Copy<T>() where T : Animal
```

When this method is overridden in the Lion class:

```
public class Lion : Animal
{
    string roar = "Roar";
}
```

i wish to return a copy of this lion without its references. So what i think it should be overridden like is this:

```
public abstract T Copy<T>()
{
    return new Lion(){ 
        roar = this.roar;
    }
}
```

but this is not allowed, because Lion cannot be converted to the T type(which is an Animal).

This is a understandable error, becouse not every Animal is necessarily a Lion.

But how can i set this situation up where the copy method knows it supposed to return the subclass, Lion in this case, and not have to do all kinds of casting to the correct type? And still have every animal have a method Copy().

Comment: Why do you think it is useful to force all subclasses to have such a `Copy` method? You could just declare a non-generic `Copy` in each of your subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a generic method in this case, because every `Lion` is an `Animal`, so you can simply make `Copy` return an `Animal`

```cs
public abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract Animal Copy();
}

public class Lion : Animal
{
    public string Roar {get; set;} = "Roar";
    
    public override Animal Copy()
    {
        return new Lion
        {
            Roar = this.Roar
        };
    }
}
```

Then testing it like so:

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    var lion1 = new Lion();
    var lion2 = lion1.Copy();
    
    Console.WriteLine(lion1 == lion2);
}
```

Prints `false` to the console, as expected because C# classes are reference types and the default `==` implementation checks for reference equals on classes and our two lions aren't the same object in memory.

Now every subclass of `Animal` must implement the method `Copy` returning an `Animal`. Which animal that is doesn't matter

Comment: This is a great solution, but when I want to use the Roar variable I still have to cast to the Lion type, which I want to do as little as possible. If this is necessary and cant be changed the so be it. But it will still bug me that there is no other way to do this than with a cast

Comment: That smells like an architectural mistake. If you need to directly access values on classes that inherit from an abstract class, then either the abstract class isn't needed, or that property should be on the base abstract class. In this case, something like `Sound`, because (almost) every animal makes some kind of sound. Otherwise I recommend you go with what Lasse V. Karlsen recommended, as it's not more than your attempt right now

Comment: How is it an architectural mistake that I want to be able to access the values of a inherited class? Instead of the 'Sound', lets say I want to access the 'Mane' of a Lion, then it would be logical that Lion still inherits from Animal, and inherits a 'Sound'. But shouldn't I still be able to access the 'Mane' of the Lion?

Comment: If you need to access say `Mane`, then you shouldn't cast your Lion to an Animal in the first place. Which brings us back to what you're trying to achieve by making `Copy` generic, and the solution to that is what Lasse V. Karlsen suggests in their answer

Answer (score 1):

You can not use generics in this situation, they don't support what you want to do.

However, if you're on C# 9 you can use the new "Covariant return types" support.

Specifically, you can write your code like this:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract Animal Copy();
}

public class Lion : Animal
{
    public override Lion Copy() => new Lion();
    //               ^
    //  notice that I used Lion here, not Animal
}
```

If you're calling `Copy` through a reference declared as being of type `Animal` but referencing an instance of `Lion`, you will get back a value typed to `Animal`, holding a `Lion` reference.

However, if you're calling `Copy` through a reference typed to `Lion`, you will get back a reference typed to `Lion` as well.

Example:

```
Animal a = new Lion();
Animal c = a.Copy(); <-- holding a Lion, but type is Animal

Lion l = new Lion();
Lion l2 = l.Copy();  <-- type is now Lion as well
```

If you're not on C# 9, a different option would be to make the Copy method know the type of the derived class, by making Animal generic:

```
void Main()
{
    Animal<Lion> a = new Lion();
    Lion c1 = a.Copy(); // <-- notice that this is now typed to Lion as well
    
    Lion l = new Lion();
    Lion c2 = l.Copy();
}

public abstract class Animal<T> where T : Animal<T>
{
    public abstract T Copy();
}

public class Lion : Animal<Lion>
{
    public override Lion Copy() => new Lion();
}
```

This, however, means you always have to declare `Animal` as the right type of animal so you lose some of the benefits of having this base class.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upgrade to C# 9, and the second solution seems a bit excessive, just for a single method, to me